# Creating VHD using Microsoft's Systernals Disk2VHD program of production box

Tags: hyper-v, vhd, vhdx

I created a VHD file of our small production server (hosting internal web pages for the company). I'd like to set up the VHD up as a dev server so that it'll be a mirror of the production system and I know the two environments are the same. It'll be a connected to our Windows Server 2016 with Hyper-V.

What changes do I need to make so that it can co-exist on our network with the production server, other than the IP address? Is simply updating the IP enough? *Licensing is handled through our MSDN account so that is covered.*

Comment: You'll need to change the computer name.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that - is changing it in System Properties good or do I need to do this in the registry?

Comment: You do it in the System Properties. If the server is running SQL Server or Sharepoint Server you'll also need to take steps to rename the SQL and/or Sharepoint instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to run a sysprep generalize on the server before allocating it a network card.

Without a generalize, renaming it can be dangerous to make, as it can lockout your other server out of the domain, as technically both server got the same SID, thus a rename can affect the computer account in your active directory.

Comment: `SID` is the word I couldn't remember earlier (why I was asking about the registry). Thanks. Its been years since I dealt with adding machines to the network.

Comment: Adding a link to Microsoft's sysprep https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation.